# Sutta Reference - Sound and musical instruments metaphors in the Suttas

Tags: reference-request, consciousness, conditionality

I am looking for a specific sutta wherein the conditionality and insubstantiality of the existential process of a sentient being, or consciousness, is made plain by use of the simile of a resonating musical instrument being struck by the player's hand, the sound of which, resonating for awhile, then slowly fades away.

Any references, anyone ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Ha, I got it at last. This is taken from a footnote in the book 'The Workings of Kamma' : ... The Buddha makes this kind of distinction when He explains that the tune of a lute is not waiting inside the lute, but arises owing to conditions: 
the physical components of the lute and the musician's playing on it 
(S.IV.I.xix.9 'Vm-Opama-Suttam' ('The Lute-Simile Sutta')). And 
VsM.xx.723 'Magg-Amagga-Ndna-Dassana-Visuddhi-Niddeso' ('Ex- 
position of the Path&Non-Path-Knowledge & Vision Purification') 
PP.xx.96 explains also: '. . .

Answer (score 2):

> This is a partial index of the similes and metaphors that appear in the suttas available at Access to Insight (/ZzE). Only the imagery that illustrates points of Dhamma is included here; imagery that serves primarily a literary or narrative function is not included (e.g., Ambapali's description of her long-lost youthful beauty). The subject of each image is given in the braces {}. The tilde (~) stands for the head-word in a given entry... **[Index of Similes](http://accesstoinsight.eu/index-similes_en.html)**

*Tuning a stringed instrument:
{right effort} [AN 6.55](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/an/an06/an06.055.than_en.html#tuning)*

Meta-ontopic-Drum:

> "Thus you should train yourselves: 'We will listen when discourses that are words of the Tathagata — deep, deep in their meaning, transcendent, connected with emptiness — are being recited. We will lend ear, will set our hearts on knowing them, will regard these teachings as worth grasping & mastering.' That's how you should train yourselves." - [Ani Sutta: The Peg/Drum](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/sn/sn20/sn20.007.than_en.html)

In reagard of the meaning behind in proper context:

*Painting of a woman or man:
{not-self} [SN 22.100](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/sn/sn22/sn22.100.than_en.html#painter); {nutriment} [SN 12.64](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/sn/sn12/sn12.064.than_en.html#picture)*

May it be of the origins use for you, Fabien

Comment: Why the downvotes to this answer? Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1):

[SN 35.246](https://suttacentral.net/en/sn35.246) is close but not quite.

> *“Suppose, bhikkhus, there was a king or a royal minister who had never before heard the sound of a lute. He might hear the sound of a
>   lute and say: ‘Good man, what is making this sound—so tantalizing, so
>   lovely, so intoxicating, so entrancing, so enthralling?’
>   They would say to him: ‘Sire, it is a lute that is making this
>   sound—so tantalizing, so lovely, so intoxicating, so entrancing, so
>   enthralling.’ He would reply: ‘Go, man, bring me that lute.’*
>
> *“They would bring him the lute and tell him: ‘Sire, this is that lute, the sound of which was so tantalizing, so lovely, so
>   intoxicating, so entrancing, so enthralling.’ The king would say:
>   ‘I’ve had enough with this lute, man. Bring me just that sound.’ The
>   men would reply: ‘This lute, sire, consists of numerous components, of
>   a great many components, and it gives off a sound when it is played
>   upon with its numerous components; that is, in dependence on the
>   parchment sounding board, the belly, the arm, the head, the strings,
>   the plectrum, and the appropriate effort of the musician. So it is,
>   sire, that this lute consisting of numerous components, of a great
>   many components, gives off a sound when it is played upon with its
>   numerous components.’*
>
> *“The king would split the lute into ten or a hundred pieces, then he would reduce these to splinters. Having reduced them to splinters, he
>   would burn them in a fire and reduce them to ashes, and he would
>   winnow the ashes in a strong wind or let them be carried away by the
>   swift current of a river. Then he would say: ‘A poor thing, indeed
>   sir, is this so-called lute, as well as anything else called a lute.
>   How the multitude are utterly heedless about it, utterly taken in by
>   it!’*
>
> *“So too, bhikkhus, a bhikkhu investigates form to the extent that there is a range for form, he investigates feeling to the extent that
>   there is a range for feeling, he investigates perception to the extent
>   that there is a range for perception, he investigates volitional
>   formations to the extent that there is a range for volitional
>   formations, he investigates consciousness to the extent that there is
>   a range for consciousness. As he investigates form to the
>   extent that there is a range for form … consciousness to the extent
>   that there is a range for consciousness, whatever notions of ‘I’ or
>   ‘mine’ or ‘I am’ had occurred to him before no longer occur to him.”*

---

[AN 8.46](https://suttacentral.net/en/an8.46) not close but interesting.

> *Those deities sang, one danced, and one snapped her fingers. Just as, when a musical quintet is well trained and its rhythm well
>   coordinated, and it is composed of skilled musicians, its music is
>   exquisite, tantalizing, lovely, captivating, and intoxicating,
>   just so those deities’ performance was exquisite,
>   tantalizing, lovely, captivating and intoxicating. Thereupon the
>   Venerable Anuruddha drew in his sense faculties. Then those deities,
>   thinking: “Master Anuruddha is not enjoying this,” disappeared right
>   on the spot.*

Comment: Ha, thank you so much @Dhammadhatu :) I knew about SN 35.246 which is, as you say, not quite close :) But for the life of me, I can't remember where I saw that simile :)